# Avoid jQuery Mobile to force script/CSS reload using _=TIMESTAMP query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As far as I know, if you want to load JavaScript or CSS files together with a specific page that is automatically loaded via ajax then you have to put the CSS/JavaScript references within the `<div data-role="page">` container.

Example:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="e">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/plugins/plugins.js"></script>
```

In general, this works fine. However, somewhere along the way, the script url gets modified:

```
/js/some_sepcial_script.js becomes e.g. js/some_sepcial_script.js?_=1299308309681
```

Where `1299308309681` is the current Unix timestamp which changes on every request and thus prevents caching. I am pretty sure that this is intended behaviour but does anyone know how you can prevent the timestamp from being appended to the script/CSS urls if you want to make the file cacheable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:?

```
$.ajax ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX response */
    cache: false
});
```

It should globally change ajax requests. I'm just not sure about external scripts.

[EDIT]

This is the source code involved for jquery mobile 1.0a3:

```
var all = $("<div></div>");
                //workaround to allow scripts to execute when included in page divs
                all.get(0).innerHTML = html;
                to = all.find('[data-role="page"], [data-role="dialog"]').first();

                //rewrite src and href attrs to use a base url
                if( !$.support.dynamicBaseTag ){
                    var newPath = path.get( fileUrl );
                    to.find('[src],link[href]').each(function(){
                        var thisAttr = $(this).is('[href]') ? 'href' : 'src',
                            thisUrl = $(this).attr(thisAttr);

                        //if full path exists and is same, chop it - helps IE out
                        thisUrl.replace( location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname, '' );

                        if( !/^(\w+:|#|\/)/.test(thisUrl) ){
                            $(this).attr(thisAttr, newPath + thisUrl);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Nothing on there adds a cache preventing param.

[EDIT 2]

I know this goes beyond troubleshooting to a work around but have you tried dynamically loading the js like explained here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

(I know it can be done through jQuery but for testing purposes I'm trying to avoid jQuery)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately it does not seem to work in this case. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nothing in the source code seems to add a cache preventing param and I can't seem to reproduce the problem on a test server. What version are you using and is a live example available?

Comment: Yes, I looked at this part, too. Everything is fine in there. Perhaps this issues has something to do with http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3677 ?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't seem to be related. If jQuery mobile doesn't add it and it's not technically an ajax request which jQuery will prevent cache then it has to be from either another plugin or from your direct output.

Comment: 1. Is is a CMS?
2. Are you getting ?_=1299308309681 from dynamic source or output source (inspect element vs view source)
3. Any cache or loading related plugins installed?

Comment: @J.Romero: I suspect that [this part of jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5/src/ajax/script.js#L19-L28) may be causing that problem – see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202330/avoid-jquery-mobile-to-force-script-css-reload-using-timestamp-query-string-par#5202678) for a possible workaround.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments. Here are the answers to your questions: I'm not using a CMS and I am pretty sure that no other javascript plugin adds the timestamp to the urls.

The Timestammp is not part of the original source code and gets appended dynamically somewhere between clicking a link and the actual ajax request triggered by clicking the link.

I Hope this gives you some clues?

Comment: Added yet another possible solution (see answer), loading js script dynamically.

Comment: Hi, using jQuery 1.5.2 / jQuery Mobile Alpha 4 the suggested solution $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true }) works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if I include jQuery 1.4.3 instead of 1.5 everything works fine. That's a sufficient solution for me. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: That's the right thing to do with JQM - test with other jquery versions. Downgrading is sometimes helpful too. 1.4.3 should not be used with alpha3 at all - it lacks support for some minor features.

Comment: yes, as naugtur said, unfortunately some jQuery Mobile features only seem to work with jQuery 1.5, e.g. fixed navbars or data-icons. Pehaps anyone has a solution to the "?_=TIMESTAMP" problem?

Comment: this loading thing is just a hack for people that can't organize the app correctly. I would not recommend using it at all. Just create a function that reacts on `pagecerate` or `pageshow` and verify if `data-url` says it's your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter("script", function (s) {
    if (s.cache === undefined) {
        s.cache = true;
    }
});
```

Does it change this behavior?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code snippet. I tried it but the behaviour did not change. The Timestamp (in milliseconds) gets still appended.